# graphana query ERROR expected type instant vector in aggregation expression, got range vector

Tags: function, graph, prometheus, metrics, promql

Im trying to write a query (PromQl) in graphana

increase(sum(Workflow_seconds_count{datapoint="DOB__TIMER"}[5m]))

Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:14: parse error: expected type instant vector in aggregation expression, got range vector

why is it, can anyone explain ?

Comment: You misplaced your functions: it should be `sum(increase(Workflow_seconds_count{datapoint="DOB__TIMER"}[5m]))`

Comment: isnt functionaly increase(sum()) and sum(increase()) different
you mean to say increase(sum()) is functionally wrong

Comment: in v8 of grapfana i have seen where increase(sum()) was giving results

Comment: i moved my grafana version from v10.1.0 to v8.5.6
increase(sum()) was working on a grafana dashboard which was on v8 and i was on v10
so i downgraded in hope to increase(sum()) works

Comment: if i want a similar functionality to increase(sum()) on version 10 
what queries i can use

Comment: What I was saying, is that you have range selector in inner call, and thus you query will work if change places of functions. And regarding sum and increase: it's long re ognized that sum should be applied after increase, because otherwise you'll have problems with counter resets, and also will need to use subquery syntax, that has its own issues.

Comment: increase(sum(metric[range])) does this ever work in prometheus 
i mean without error , i get error when i run this
parse error: expected type instant vector in aggregation expression, got range vector

Comment: is this expected behaviour

Comment: No, this query will never work: range selector must be in `increase` parameters, not in `sum` parameters.

Comment: increase(sum(metric)[range]) will work??

Comment: No, but `increase(sum(metric)[range:])` will. But [you shouldn't use it still](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate/), unless you have a really good understanding what you are doing.

Comment: increase(sum(metric)[range:]) what does this actually mean 
can you explain with an example